# remove duplicates text from a dict like string

Tags: python

```
txt='''Product Dimensions: 7.1 x 3.1 x 4.7 inches
Item Weight: 5.6 ounces
Shipping Weight: 10.4 ounces ( View Link) 10.4 ounces
Item_ID: 2548
Customer Reviews: 4.9 out of 5 stars 450 ratings 4.9 out of 5 stars
Date: May 26, 2017'''
```

I am reading a bunch of txt files, I want to remove the the texts which are repeated inside the new "row"

expected output is

```
Product Dimensions: 7.1 x 3.1 x 4.7 inches
Item Weight: 5.6 ounces
Shipping Weight: 10.4 ounces ( View Link)
Item_ID: 2548
Customer Reviews: 4.9 out of 5 stars 450 ratings
Date: May 26, 2017
```

the keys are never repeated, but the values may contain repeated text which I want to remove, I am not sure if regex can do it, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the repeated text always at the end of the values?

Comment: @quamrana yes, but it could have more have more than one repetition, for example 
`10.4 ounces ( View Link) 10.4 ounces ( View Link) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be a bit more brute force and just search for the whole duplicate phrase:

```
def removeRepeats(value):
    l = len(value)
    half = l //2
    lastRemainder = value
    for i in range(1, half+1):
        target = value[-i:]
        remainder = value[:-i]
        if target in remainder:
            lastRemainder = remainder
        else:
            return lastRemainder

    return value
```

Sample run:

```
print(removeRepeats('Customer Reviews: 5 out of 5 stars 450 ratings 5 out of 5 stars'))
Customer Reviews: 5 out of 5 stars 450 ratings
```

Answer (score 2):

Well removing duplicates from a list is a common problem, so if we could get the text to be a list that would help. We can do that by:

```
lst = text.split()
```

And now to remove the duplicates we would usually do:

```
list(set(lst))
```

But that does not ensure order. From Python 3.6, `dicts` **do** ensure **insertion** order, so we can use:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
```

Now we just need to make that list back into a string, so we can use:

```
' '.join(dict.fromkeys(lst))
```

And all together, on your example we would get:

```py
for row in txt.splitlines():
    print(' '.join(dict.fromkeys(row.split())))
```

Which gives:

```
Product Dimensions: 7.1 x 3.1 4.7 inches
Item Weight: 5.6 ounces
Shipping Weight: 10.4 ounces ( View Link)
Item_ID: 2548
Customer Reviews: 4.9 out of 5 stars 450 ratings
Date: May 26, 2017
```

---

If using an older version of Python, you can replace the `dict` with [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Hmm, fails when there is legitimate duplicates. eg. `'Customer Reviews: 5 out of 5 stars 450 ratings 5 out of 5 stars'` => `'Customer Reviews: 5 out of stars 450 ratings'`

Comment: That's is true... But nothing is perfect so we wouldn't expect 5 out of 5 ratings... :D Just kidding, how would you advise on qualifying a legitimate duplicate @quamrana?